# SQL Query slow during batch update of table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a postgresql table with about 250K records.  It gets updated a few times an hour.  However, the entire table gets deleted and new records added.  (Batch job).

I don't have much control over that process.  During the time it takes the transaction to delete/re-load queries on the table basically lock/hang until the job finishes.  The job takes about a minute to run.   We have real time users looking at this data (which is spatial data on a map with a time slider).   They recogize the lost records very easily.

Is there anything that can be done about these 60 or so second query times during the update.  I've thought about loading into a 2nd table, dropping the original and renaming the 2nd to the original but that introduces more chance of error.   Are there any settings that will just grab data as is and not necessarily look for a consistent view of the data.
Basically just looking for ideas on how to handle this situation.
I'm running postgresql 9.3.1
Thanks

Comment: What errors you expect with temp table solution? If you drop prod and rename temp to prod in transaction then there is no risk of errors. You will have to wait for transactions using that table to finish and will lock any new ones, but if those are short transactions then I don't think this should be a problem.

Comment: Can DDL be handled in a transaction?  I guess if thats true that that would work.  I was worried that a DROP table would be commited and then follow on commands would fail... But if I can transaction them all together then might be okay.

Comment: Looks like most DDL can be handled in a transaction.   So I think I'll try that approach.  Thanks for verifying my thoughts!

Comment: No problem. Just remember that long lasting transactions will create locking issues, but I think you would get exactly the same problem with delete/truncate anyway.